# Why AdMob AppOpenAd shows with the status bar on some devices

Tags: android, admob, ads, android-fullscreen

Why on some devices [AppOpenAd](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open) shows with the status bar?
Samsung A20s, Nexus 5x

[image: it looks like this]

Comment: What's the question? What answer would you like from us?

Comment: @FreeLearning AppOpenAd should appear without the status bar(fullscreen ad)

Comment: It seems a bug, post the question here (https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk), for this case maybe Google employees can reply better than us.